# How to add the opening cash balance with the total opening sales?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have the following table where the seller `id_seller` performs the opening with the start date of activities and the opening balance. It will be known that this box is open by having the status at 0:

`tbl_cashier`:

[image]

Taking into account the opening date of the box, I need to list the total sales that the seller has made from its opening date until the seller closes his box:

`tbl_invoice`:

[image]

Considering the above, prepare the following query:

```
SELECT
ca.id_cashier,
ca.open_date,
ca.open_amount,
ca.close_date,
ca.open_amount + SUM(i.amount_total) AS total_amount,
ca.status
FROM tbl_cashier ca
LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice i ON ca.id_seller=i.id_seller
WHERE ca.id_seller=6
AND i.payer_date BETWEEN ca.open_date AND ca.close_date
GROUP BY ca.id_cashier
```

Having the following output:

[image]

The result is correct since it adds the initial opening balance 100.00 + the two sales that were made from the beginning to the closing 10.00 + 10.10, this gives us an equal of 120.10

Now the problem is that I need both records to be shown, that is, the closed box and the open box of the `tbl_cashier` table and when adding this WHERE `i.payer_date BETWEEN ca.open_date AND ca.close_date` condition it only shows me the records of the closed boxes, then, ¿ How can I show both data?

I tried adding this condition but I can't get the open box in the query listing:

```
AND i.payer_date BETWEEN ca.open_date AND ca.close_date OR i.payer_date BETWEEN ca.open_date AND ca.open_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cases like this, where one of your `BETWEEN` bounds may be `NULL`, you can't use `BETWEEN`, and must instead explicitly check whether each bound is `NULL`. In your particular scenario, it will never be the case that `ca.open_date` is `NULL`, so we don't need to check that condition.

Note also that if you want to correctly compute `total_amount` for sessions where there were no invoices, it is correct to do a left join (as you are already doing), but you will need to coalesce the output of `SUM()`, as in that case the group's set of `i.amount_total` values will be `{NULL}`, meaning `SUM(i.amount_total)` will be `NULL`. If you don't do this, then you will see `total_amount` as `NULL` in the result set, rather than the opening/closing balance. You must also ensure that such "empty left joins" are retained in the result set by allowing `i.id_invoice IS NULL` in your `WHERE` clause.

Putting all these things together gives us the following:

```sql
SELECT
    ca.id_cashier,
    ca.open_date,
    ca.open_amount,
    ca.close_date,
    ca.open_amount + COALESCE(SUM(i.amount_total), 0) AS total_amount,
    ca.status
FROM
    tbl_cashier AS ca
    LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice AS i USING (id_seller)
WHERE
    ca.id_seller = 6
    AND (
        i.id_invoice IS NULL -- No invoices were generated whilst this box was open. Make sure we still return this row.
        OR (
            i.payer_date >= ca.open_date -- Only show invoices generated after the box was opened
            AND (
                ca.close_date IS NULL -- The box is still open / hasn't yet been closed
                OR i.payer_date <= ca.close_date -- Only show invoices generated before the box was closed
            )
        )
    )
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Friend I have a problem, I know that it comes out of the context of my question, but I am listing this data in a pagination now I want to add a search filter add other tables to the query, how do I perform this type of filter without affecting the result of the solution? For example search by name or other data: `OR ((? IS NULL) OR u.first_name LIKE ? OR u.last_name LIKE ? OR ent.tradename LIKE ? OR bo.tradename LIKE ?)`

Comment: That WHERE extension looks fine to me. Not sure what you mean by "add other tables to the query" though. A query only returns a single table. If you're trying to squash different sorts of data together into a single table/result set, that's just asking for trouble.

Comment: This is how everything works for me: https://ideone.com/XxkwSG, I just wanted to add filters to the query, but if I add them it stops working correctly, even if they are not extensive filters like the ones I mentioned, but filter by name of the seller for example  https://ideone.com/JnECMm but it no longer works with the solution you have given me, if you can tell me something, thanks :)

Comment: Oh, I see now. You can't use `? IS NULL` in the way you want to, because `?` would be a field name like `u.first_name`. You can't prepare a statement like that; each instance of `?` should be a value, not a field name. For example, `u.first_name LIKE ?` is fine because`?` would be a string like `'%John%'`. You probably want `u.first_name IS NULL` instead of `? IS NULL`. If you wish, you can then rewrite `(u.first_name IS NULL OR u.first_name LIKE ?)` as `COALESCE(u.first_name LIKE ?, TRUE)`.

Comment: Friend I need help, I just realized that if there is no sale in the tbl_invoice table on the date that the opening is made, the user is not shown in the list, it is only shown when the user has previously made sales and that is wrong, it is incorrect, since the user must first open the box and then make the sales.